# What is the difference between Disallow and Allow?

Tags: google-adsense, robots.txt, web-crawlers

I had 2 questions in my mind:

1. what is the difference between `Allow` and `Disallow`?
2. which one should I use to allow Google bot for AdSense?

> ```
> User-agent: Mediapartners-Google  
> Disallow:
>
> User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*  
> Allow: /
> ```

Comment: Crucially it's `Disallow:` without any value and `Allow:`+`/` (with a value). The first means _disallow nothing_, whilst the second means `allow everything`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is `Allow` is not defined in [specifications of robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org).

However, several web crawlers understand `Allow` like `Disallow`. It's the case for `Mediapartners-Google` bot. Therefore, you can use lines you want but if you want to respect specifications, choose the first ones:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google  
Disallow:
```

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/ isn't opening for me. Can you provide any other reference?

Comment: @Simon Walker: this is the website where specifications are defined. However, the website is currently down.

Comment: And if iam not using the above code in robots.txt, can google my website??

Comment: If you don't use the code I mentioned, you didn't restrict your website access to `Mediapartners-Google` bot. Therefore, `Mediapartners-Google` bot will crawl your website.

Comment: ...unless there is another, perhaps more general, group in your robots.txt file that catches this crawler?